# Impossible to delete old dags in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to delete some old dags in airflow. I know that since Airflow 1.10.1 you can delete them using the UI.

[image]

Depite clicking in the red cross, airflow makes as it deletes the dag but later on it reapears.

As I have acces to the DB I tried to delete some dags using:

```
delete from task_fail  where dag_id='';
delete from task_instance where dag_id ='';
delete from serialized_dag  where dag_id='';
delete from xcom where dag_id='';
delete from log where dag_id='';
delete from dag_tag where dag_id='';
delete from job where dag_id='';
delete from task_reschedule where dag_id ='';
delete from sla_miss where dag_id ='';
delete from dag_run where dag_id='';
delete from dag where dag_id ='';
```

It do the sames as the UI, dissapears and later on reappear.

I read that it uses `file_name` to recreate the dag despite change the dag name on the file.

**For instance:**

my_file.py --> Dag_id= MY_DAG_ID

my_file.py --> Dag_id= MY_NEW_DAG_ID

It will show two dags, MY_DAG_ID & MY_NEW_DAG_ID, and i can't delete MY_DAG_ID.

How can I solve that?
The only way is to rename or create a new file for the new dag?

Comment: When the DAG reappears, does it have the run details as well or a blank DAG pops up ? If blank DAG pops up, then you have to remove the dag file from your storage as well.

Comment: It is blank, but what if i used the original file to create a new dag?

Comment: If two files appear in your storage with same DAG name then there would be issues. If you have modified the original file, renamed the DAG then the previous DAG should not appear in the UI.

Comment: I tiddy up all dags, and then deleted them and finally its fine but it takes some time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what version of airflow are you running ? When I delete it from the UI it asks me to remove the DAG file from my volume. I do that and then after sometime(based on your dag refresh interval) it cleans up the DAG. So steps are

- delete from UI using the red button
- Remove the DAG file from the volume which is being scanned periodically.

Let me know.